# ImportError: cannot import name 'speech_v1p1beta1'

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

i`m trying to run the following script in python which converts video file into text:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
client = speech.SpeechClient()

with open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US',
    model='video')

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print('-' * 20)
    print('First alternative of result {}'.format(i))
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

when i run this script i get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'speech_v1p1beta1'

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running
`$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`to update your dependency.